# I load a lot of data from different categories and turn them into pins but not every piece of information gets into a pin on the map

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I gather a lot of data from my DB that i turn into pins and all of the pins does not get added on the map (i think there are around 100 pins or something like that).

When I cut out part of the code that generate pins then I can see new pins that I did not see before when I loaded all of the pins. What do i need to do so each of everyone of them gets added to the map?
Is there a limit of pins or something like that? Or do I need await something else (beside the await of the db info)to make it wait for all of the generated pins?

```
private async Task<List<Pin>> LoadData() 
{
    var pins = new List<Pin> ();

    var getItems = await phpApi.getInfo ();

        foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

            longString = currentItem ["long"].ToString (); 
            latString = currentItem ["lat"].ToString (); 

                if (App.value1 == 0) { 
                        var pin = new Pin ();
                        pin.Position = new Position (latString, longString);
                        pin.Label = "testlabel";
                        pin.Address = "testadress";

                        pins.Add (pin);
                    }

                if (App.value2 == 0) {

                        var pin = new Pin ();
                        pin.Position = new Position (latString, longString);
                        pin.Label = "testlabel";
                        pin.Address = "testadress";
                        pins.Add (pin);
                }

                if (App.value3 == 0) {

                        //and add pins here as well. etc
                }
            }
      }
}
```

This is how i get the data.

```
static public async Task<JObject> getInfo ()
{
var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("mySQLdb");

var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

return jsonResult;

}
```

Comment: Your 2nd if case creates a Pin but does not add it to the pins collection.

Comment: It is there. So that is not the issue. Weird i managed to delete it when i posted the example here on stackoverflow. Updated the code now with the "add". Thx for pointing it out.

Comment: How do you "know" that all of the pins are not shown?  Are you just guessing by looking at the map?  That's not very accurate - pins can easily stack on top of each other.  Or they might be displayed outside the bounds of the map.  You should be able to easily count the number of elements in your data, and the number of pins in the Map's collection to verify that they have all been processed.

Comment: The database i am loading from has all the info there so I can see easily when I search the pins which one isnt there. And when I cut out some of the code I see pins on countries that didnt have a pin before. So some pins does not show when I load the pins which is strange. Have you heard of this issue before?

Comment: As Jason mentions, you should easily be able to gather the `.Count` of your `getItems["results"]` and ensure that every object gets placed into a respective `Pin` list. As mentioned in a previous question, you can just use  different lists to place your pins. Use your `if/else` statements to collect these items in each respective list.