# How can I send all of my information from my DB into a pin and send it to another page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have multiple data that I receive from my database and I want all of it to be sent in with my pin, but I am not sure how I should do it. Right now I send `pin.Name + pin.Address`, but I want everything from that particular pin info to get to the next page. So in my case, for example, phone number, URL, etc., but as I am now sending my pin as the sender, I do not know how to send all of the info.

This is the code I am working with:

```
private async Task<List<Pin>> LoadData() 
{
    var pins = new List<Pin> ();    
    var getItems = await phpApi.getInfo ();

    foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {
        longString = currentItem ["long"].ToString (); 
        latString = currentItem ["lat"].ToString ();
        nameString = currentItem ["name"].ToString (); 
        adressString = currentItem ["adress"].ToString (); 
        phoneString = currentItem ["phone"].ToString (); 
        urlString = currentItem ["URL"].ToString (); 

        var pin = new Pin ();
        pin.Position = new Position (latString, longString);
        pin.Label = nameString;
        pin.Address = adressString;
        pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1;
        pins.Add (pin);
    }
}

void onButtonClicked1 (object s, EventArgs a)
{
    Pin pin = (Pin)s;
    Navigation.PushModalAsync (new DetailPage ( pin.Label, pin.Address)); // How do I include all of the strings here to the next page?
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the constructor of your custom `DetailPage`, you should be able to receive the `Pin` object.

EX:

```
public class MyDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyDetailPage(Pin pin)
    {
       //Do whatever you need to do to your Pin here. 
    }
}
```

However, I would probably say it would be easier with a custom object.

i.e.

```
public class MyCustomPinHolder
{
    private string Phone { get; set; }
    private string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    private Pin Pin { get; set;}
}
```

Some notes:

- You may want to consider using a method of saving the item to a database/local cache.
- You can then pull the respective item from your database/cache given a unique id.

Comment: Ok, but with the first example, I am not binding the (in my case) phoneString or urlString to the pin, so it wont be able to find it when I try to get that piece of information out with the pin. ...? Right? So how could I bind that into the pin? (I am actually using Pin.BindingContext right now to something else but is there any other Pin. function i could use?)

Comment: You can add all of those properties into a PinHolder object like shown above. You would have to populate those fields with your API results. The Properties are separate to the Pin object in my example.

Comment: So instead of going `var pin = new Pin ();` inside the loop, i should just adjust the code with: `var myCustomPin = new MyCustomPinHolder ();
        myCustomPin.Pin;` assuming i make the Pin a public string instead of private

Comment: Yulp you can do something like that. You would then change the `MyDetailPage` constructor to take the `MyCustomPinHolder` class instead. Then you will have both a `Pin` object and any `Properties` you added in it as well.

Comment: Okay thanks alot. I think i will be able to make it work from here. Thanks

Comment: Did you see my other post btw? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298298/i-load-alot-of-data-from-different-categories-and-turn-them-into-pins-but-not-ev maybe u have heard of that issue before.